# Android Navigation Drawer -App crashes on Launch

Tags: android

Hi this is my layout code-

My App is crashing everytime on Launch. What am i doing wrong here?This is a navigation drawer template.It has a textview in drawer.The main window also has a textview. There are no other controls.

```
<DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    >
<!--MainWindow-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MainWindow" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <!--Drawer-->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Drawer" />

    </RelativeLayout>     </DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You don't seem to close the `<DrawerLayout>` tag...

Comment: @Kroltan I have closed it , for some reason stackoverflow didnt pick it up.

Comment: post the exception, so we can see what's going on